# Compare multiple columns

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, arraylist

Is there an effective way to compare the elements of a list? Some background on the matter:

I am parsing data then storing it in a list. I will then query an Oracle DB for a list that matches on some elements (ID Name Description). I have been creating a data structure then storing that to the list. The problem is how to compare the contents. I need to account for 4 scenarios.

1. The new data is completely new (add row)
2. The new data mostly matches existing data (update previous row)
3. There is data that exists in the DB not in new data, but matches on some data. (Status need to change to show that the issue has been canceled).
4. Data matches exactly (update time if changed, else do not change)

Comment: Could you give a couple of examples of what you want to do?

Comment: You are looking up exactly what in the database? What are you supposed to modify, the list in memory or update the database? Have you written something yet, where are you stuck?

Comment: I have written a bunch of code, but find myself stuck on the same portion of comparing.

Answer (score 0):

Create an object that describes the row. Use `ComparisonChain` for your functional requirement.

```
public int compareTo(Foo that) {
     return ComparisonChain.start()
         .compare(this.aString, that.aString)
         .compare(this.anInt, that.anInt)
         .compare(this.anEnum, that.anEnum, Ordering.natural().nullsLast())
         .result();
   }
```

http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CommonObjectUtilitiesExplained#equals

Comment: I was considering Guava but felt that is couldn't do what I wanted.

Lets say one row looks like the following (assume the first two columns are the ID that I care that link the data)
[a,b,111,222,333,444]
row 2 looks like
[a,b,111,222,444,555]
This case I want to add a separate row.
Let's say in the same message I get:
[a,b,666,777,888,999]
Then I want to add this as a new row then update row 1 to have a status of canceled.

Comment: Sorry not following. But it seems obvious you need your own implementation

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, these methods can be of some help to you:

[`List.contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29)

[`Collections.frequency`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#frequency%28java.util.Collection,%20java.lang.Object%29)

[`Collections.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29)

Comment: I feel this is too primitive. There is also the caveat that The lists may not have the same number of collumns. When I query the db for existing data. I also store the ROWID. The case of new data will not have the ROWID because they are not in the DB yet. In this case List.contains would always return false.